# Solaris 11.3 and SSHD privilege separation

Tags: solaris, openssh

I'm working on a OpenSSH server installation on Solaris 11.3. When I build OpenSSH 7.7p1 from source and install it `make` dies at the end after installing the components:

```
$ sudo gmake install
...

/usr/gnu/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/etc
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
gmake: [check-config] Error 255 (ignored)
```

When I check Solaris' existing installation:

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -V
Sun_SSH_2.2, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x1000110f

$ sudo id sshd
id: invalid user name: "sshd"

$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i privilege
$
```

So the stock OpenSSH is kind of old and does not use the feature.

Here are my points of contention:

- Privilege separation has been around [since at least 2003](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep-faq.html)
- The OpenSSH portability team decided privilege separation should be used on this platform
- The Solaris team decided decided privilege separation should *not* be used on this platform
- Solaris may provide complimentary security controls, like roles, in lieu of privilege separation

Additional information includes (1) no useful information about Solaris install in the OpenSSH docs, and (2) questions for the Solaris build and install to the SSH mailing list went unanswered.

So my question is, do I (1) follow Solaris and drop privilege separation; or (2) follow best practice and use privilege separation?

Or maybe a combination, like (1) use privilege separation and (2) add SSHD to a network role? (I'm still investigating the other security controls applied to `/usr/lib/sunssh/lib/sshd`).

Comment: Does the `sshd` user exist?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - No, the user does not exist.

Comment: Try creating it ?  To /etc/group add `sshd:x:74:`, to /etc/passwd add `sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin`

Comment: @steve - Thanks. So are you saying I should use option (2) on Solaris - *"follow best practice and use privilege separation"*? And for completeness, have you run a Solaris box in the configuration? Sorry to ask. I'm still not at the point where I know what I should be doing.

Comment: Sun_SSH != OpenSSH.  Instead of doing this manually, [installing the OpenSSH package from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54793/tsk-openssh.html) will most likely already have all the required users and security controls handled for you:  `pkg install network/openssh`

Comment: Thanks @GracefulRestart. That was interesting. After installing `network/openssh` the version string for `/usr/bin/ssh` stayed the same. However, now there is a `/usr/lib/ssh/sshd` that is just as old. All Oracle did was symlink `/usr/lib/ssh/sshd` to `/usr/lib/sunssh/lib/sshd`. SSH and friends still cannot do ed25519 or ecdsa.

Comment: If the version string still says `Sun_SSH_2.2` then that is not OpenSSH.  The document I linked had instructions on how to set the default `ssh` to OpenSSH after it had been installed:  `pkg set-mediator -I openssh ssh`.  `ed25519` is supported since OpenSSH 6.5 and `ecdsa` is supported since OpenSSH 5.7.  Though I would not be surprised if Oracle does not build a recent package of OpenSSH that provides those functionalities.

Comment: Oh, thanks @GracefulRestart. I can't help but laugh at installing OpenSSH did not activate it. It is classic over-engineering by engineers. I find it humorous someone actually made the claim - and others agreed - that *"someone installing updated SSH software did not actually want to use it; so leave it deactivated. And make them RTFM to accomplish the simple task."*.